# MongoDB left join return only top 1

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've got the following 2 collections. I'm trying to do a left join with a top 1 equivalent in MongoDB.

```
// Vendors Collection
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("abc"),
  "vendorName" : "Jimmy Jones BBQ",
  "Address" : "3424 Western Ave...",
  "email" : "jimmy@mail.com"
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("def"),
  "vendorName" : "Bobby Jones BBQ",
  "Address" : "987 West Ave...",
  "email" : "bobby@mail.com"
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("ghi"),
  "vendorName" : "Henry smith BBQ",
  "Address" : "657 Western Ave...",
  "email" : "henry@mail.com"
}


// Sponsors Collection
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5aa306b958056a9e2cc52e90"),
  "vendorID" : ObjectId("abc"),
  "name" : "Mary doe"
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5aa306b958056a9e2cc52e90"),
  "vendorID" : ObjectId("abc"),
  "sponsor" : "mary doe"
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5aa306b958056a9e2cc52e90"),
  "vendorID" : ObjectId("def"),
  "name" : "mary doe"
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5aa306b958056a9e2cc52e90"),
  "vendorID" : ObjectId("ghi"),
  "name" : "mary doe"
}
```

Here is my aggregate call.

```
db.getCollection('vendors').aggregate([
    { "$match": { "retired": false } },
    { "$sort": { "name": 1 } }, 
    { "$lookup": {
         "from": "sponsors",
         "localField": "_id",
         "foreignField": "vendorID",
         "as": "sponsor"
      }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$sponsor" },
    { "$project": {
      "vendorName":1, 
      "Address":1, 
      "email":1
      "sponsor.name": 1
    } }
  ]).then(vendors => {
    console.log(vendors);
    // do stuff
  });
```

This works, however it returning multiple record for vendor ObjectId("abc") because there are multiple sponsors with the matching vendorID. I only want to top 1 to return.

```
// Results
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("abc"),
  "vendorName" : "Jimmy Jones BBQ",
  "address" : "3424 Western Ave...",
  "email" : "jimmy@mail.com",
  "sponsor" : {
      "name" : "Mary doe"
  }
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("abc"),
  "vendorName" : "Jimmy Jones BBQ",
  "address" : "3424 Western Ave...",
  "email" : "jimmy@mail.com",
  "sponsor" : {
    "name" : "Mary doe"
  }
},
,
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("def"),
  "vendorName" : "Bobby Jones BBQ",
  "address" : "987 West Ave...",
  "email" : "bobby@mail.com",
  "sponsor" : {
    "name" : "Jane doe"
  }
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("ghi"),
  "vendorName" : "Henry smith BBQ",
  "address" : "657 Western Ave...",
  "email" : "henry@mail.com",
  "sponsor" : {
    "name" : "John doe"
  }
}
```

I've tried using $group and $limit but the results were not desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and update your [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to below.

Use [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) expression  to create the top 1 sponser using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) and map the name.

```
{
  "$project":{
    "vendorName":1,
    "Address":1,
    "email":1,
    "sponsorName":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{
          "sponsorone":{
            "$arrayElemAt":["$sponsor",0]
          }
        },
       "in":"$$sponsorone.name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: np. Can I see your updated query ? make sure you use $$ when referencing the sponserone user variable. Did you get rid of unwind stage ?

Comment: My bad Veeram, your suggested code worked perfectly. It was a typo on my part. Thanks again for your help, I really appreciated!

Comment: I actually remove one of the "$$" thinking it was a typo. it worked as expect after I added the "$" back.